# Rails integration test: Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, testing

Lately I am working on my *beautiful* tests, but suddenly, after a 2 days rest, I ran again my integration tests (rake test:integration) and they don't work anymore. I really didn't do anything.

What comes is the following error:

Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.2'

The nice thing is that the server runs fine. It is just the integration test that is broken. And they use the same mysql database.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Luca

Comment: can you share your database.yml please?

Answer (score 0):

check your database.yml settings about test environment and then make in terminal

```
rake db:test:load
```

Comment: WARNING: db:test:load is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details

Answer (score 0):

Check the DB using [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) if you not find errors as user permissions... delete and create again DB for app. `rake db:drop && rake db:setup`